# Sending multiple files on different threads Sockets c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a software that transfers multiple files between different computers but i am faced with the problem of concurrency. When both threads start sending using    Task.Run() the bytes mumble up on the receiving side i.e the data clashes together. I have tried locking every possible part of my code that could cause the error all to no avail.      This is part of my code.

//code to transfer asynchronously

```
    public void StartTransferAsync(Socket socket)
    {

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    uploader = new Uploader(this, socket);
                    uploader.Upload();
                }
            });

    }
```

//code to receive the asynchronous files coming in

```
public byte[] DownloadData()
    {


            int total = 0;
            int recv = 0;
            int size = 0;
            int dataleft = 0;
            byte[] data;

            byte[] dataSize = new byte[4];
            recv = socket.Receive(dataSize, 0, 4, 0);

            size = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataSize, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Size received: {size}");
            if (size > 100038)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shii here");
            }

            dataleft = size;
            data = new byte[size];

            while (total < size)
            {
                recv = socket.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
                total += recv;
                dataleft -= recv;
            }
            return data; 


    }
```

Please help i really need this.

Comment: You'll need to use different sockets for each file, or introduce a protocol that packages up blocks of data per file to the receiving end knows which bit of data goes with which file.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I did, each packet has an ID . But data clashes due to concurrency

Comment: @kingthor You do know you can only transmit one block of data at a time right? If you have two blocks of data being transmitted at the same time it will get all jumbled up. That scenario does not even make sense